# SSH idle timeout related

Tags: ssh

Q1> Is there any relation between option a and option b mentioned below. What happens if both are configured?

```
Option a)
SSH client side config
ServerAliveInterval 300
ServerAliveCountMax 2

Option b)
SSH server side config
ClientAliveInterval 150
ClientAliveCountMax 2
```

Q2> When client or server sends a null packet to keep the session alive then will client/server respond if session is alive always? I mean whoever is sending the null packet is expecting other side to see the null packet and respond right?

Q3> What will happen if I set ClientAliveCountMax =0 in option b. Will it send null packet (even one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If both are configured, both client and server are going to try to keep the connection alive.
2. Yes, whichever side sends the null packet expects a response from the other end of the connection.
3. No, the server will not send any null packets if `ClientAliveCountMax` is set to 0.

Comment: @devejagoda about nbr 2> What I'm trying to understand is that ssh has been coded in a way that if let's say server receives a null packet from client then server will respond to that packet even if no other communication is going on at that time over the ssh channel.

Comment: @devajagoda about nbr 1> again just clarifying if both are configured then the null packet send by client will not be considered as response from client to server's null packet request right?

Comment: @Max either end will respond to the other end's null packet. If both ends are configured to use this mechanism, the first to reach its interval will send a null packet, and if the other end's response is received both will reset their timers. During normal operations, if both ends are configured like this, it will appear is if only the one with the shorter interval is sending null packets, since successful communication will reset both timers.